# Integrals and the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation, limits-without-lhopital

Hi I was trying to learn the rigorous algebraic proof for the fundamental theorem of calculus that involves the mean value theorem but there are not that many good straightforward explanations online is there an intuitive proof?. Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "rigorous algebraic proof" and "straightforward explanations" is sort of a dichotomy. The following youtube video by 3blue1brown I found gave a decent overview of FTOC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfG8ce4nNh0

Comment: Just any clear proof would help out